# Uno platform Material Button use symbolicon

Tags: uno-platform

I want to use a Material styled button in my app- but I am not able to get the settings icon to disply.  I dont mind switching from symbolicon(I believe it is failing in part because it is from the Fluent style font and Material does not have it)- but I am not sure how to go about this.  Also- how would I change the color of the ripple of a Material button?  I see in the source code for the Material button there is a pressed state- but it only has an opacity and a duration.  Since my background in light mode will be a light grey- you will never see the ripple.  Here is my code:

```
Working- but using fluent:
<Button Background="{StaticResource buttonBackground}" Click="set_Click">
                <SymbolIcon x:Name="gearIcon" Symbol="Setting" Foreground="{StaticResource buttonForeground}" >
                   
                </SymbolIcon>
            </Button>

Goal:
<material:Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialContainedButtonStyle}" Click="set_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting" Foreground="{StaticResource buttonForeground}" >
                   
                </SymbolIcon>
</material:Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material styling is done via styles only, you don't want `<material:Button`, there's no custom class named button, it uses the Uno/WinUI Button class directly.

In other words, you need `<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialContainedButtonStyle}"`

Something like this:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialContainedButtonStyle}" Click="set_Click">
   <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks Mattfillion.  I was using the materials:Button to designate material controls through: xmlns:material="using:Uno.Material.Controls"- but like you said just doing the style allowed the button itself to work.  Do you know how to change the ripple color when it is pressed?

Comment: The MaterialContainedButtonStyle is here https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Themes/blob/a9d25c27fe6f78fc85c6df48e1df7794c0ccff74/src/library/Uno.Material/Styles/Controls/Button.xaml#L143

Comment: You can see the ripple is the color of the foreground of the button (typically white or black, depending on the light or dark theme), with a set opacity. 
You can change the Foreground property directly on the Button, if you want to change the opacity, you can simply redefine MaterialPressedOpacity in your app.

Comment: Thanks- that is helpful.  I still wish we could change the ripple color itself.  But changing the opacity will work for now.

Comment: You can copy over the style and edit the color if you need the ripple to be a different color than the foreground.